# Android,What is the best way to kill AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-syncadapter

I'm using SyncAdapter in my application. My problem is if I log out and then call `ContentResolver.requestSync(myAccount, MyProvider.AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);` it still calls the parse cloud based on previous parse user data.

But before log out I clear all my database and I make sure after `ParseUser.logout();` it returns null as the current user. But when I requestSync as follows

```
@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    Log.d("Current user",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
}
```

it shows the id of previous user. What is the best way to stop sync adapter and once again start it from top so that it wont have my user id?

I tried `ContentResolver.cancelSync(myAccount, MyProvider.AUTHORITY);` to stop sync, but it still shows the user id. Can anybody help me to solve this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove and add account. accountManager.removeAccount() well this is depricated but give a try.

Comment: depricated removeAccount is working. But not the latest thing. Anyway it has solved my problem. Thank you.